# How to change wallpaper picture position through command prompt?

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, wallpaper

I have a VBScript file, that change wallpaper once per hour.
The picture position automatically changes to Fill, but I need to set it to Fit. I can change it manually each hour, but it is better make it by command, that I could add to the VBScript.

Comment: Post your code whatever you have tried till now

Comment: Ok, it is here: www.beetxt.com/xd8

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this code from google. See if this helps

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 sWinDir = oFSO.GetSpecialFolder(0)
 sWallPaper = "C:\winnt.bmp"
 ' update in registry oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper",sWallPaper 

' let the system know about the change oShell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,
```

The key WallpaperStyle from HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper has three values: 0 – Center; 1 – Tile; 2 - Stretch
Depending on how you want the picture to be displayed, you will choose one of this options.

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thx